# warning: iteration 5u invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]

Tags: c, mingw

In the below code, I am not sure why I get the warning: iteration 5u invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations] when I comment the printf(" "); statement in the for loop. How a printf statement contributes to this warning?.

Secondly, this code go to endless loop. I know array index is outside the limit when entering while loop. But when i goes negative, while loop should have terminated. But not happening. If i-- is done before entering while loop, there is no issue. If index is out of bound, I should be just getting junk result right. But why endless!

```
 int main (void)
{
   int a[]={4,6,8,2,7};
   int i=0;
   int size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);

  for(i=0;i<size;i++)
   {
      // printf(" ");
   }
 // i--; // doing i-- works fine.
   while(i>=0)
    {
      printf("%d\t",a[i]);
      i--;
    }

  return(0);

}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior causes the behavior to be undefined, and anything can happen.

Comment: When you access `a[5]`, things go haywire.  What is the value of `i` after the `for` loop?  So on the first iteration of the `while` loop, what is its value?  That's why the compiler is complaining (and why the `i--` resolves the problem).

Comment: I agree with you in case of undeifined behaviour. But here only undefined behaviour I see is when printing a[i] for the first time inside while loop. But in such case garbage is printed I guess. for loop is used only to increment the index and I do not see any issue inside for loop. Why warning points to for loop?

Answer (score 6):

> If index is out of bound, I should be just getting junk result right. But why endless!

When the `for` loop ends, the value if `i` is `5`.

In the first iteration of the `while` loop, you access `a[5]`, which leads to undefined behavior. After that, anything can happen.

Also, the `while` loop is wrong on another account. If undefined behavior was not invoked in the loop, t will execute the loop `6` times, for values of `i` equal to `5`, `4`, `3`, `2`, `1`, and `0`.

Executing `i--;` before entering the `while` loop fixes both problems.

Comment: So you mean to say if array index goes out of bound, it is not only printing junk value, but also misbehave in any manner. But why compilation warning is pointing to for loop? Why warning disappears if I just add just a printf() statement inside the for loop? So compiler behaviour is also undefined in addition to runtime undefined behavior?

Comment: @Rajesh, "yes" to the first question. I don't have answers to the other questions.

Answer (score 1):

`volatile i` helps avoiding this error message.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site! Could you add a bit of explanation why the `volatile` keyword solves this problem?